# Laravel API, getting 401 unathorized when calling from android/retrofit

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit, laravel-5.4

I'm building an android app with authentication using laravel and passport and my logout method looks like this

```
public function logout(Request $request){

        $accessToken = Auth::user()->token();

        DB::table('oauth_refresh_tokens')
            ->where('access_token_id', $accessToken->id)
            ->update(['revoked' => true]);

        $accessToken->revoke();

        return response()->json([], 204);

    }
```

i was testing it with postman and it works, it is returning 204, no content as it should be.

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIGcC.png)

but when i try to call it from android app it is always returning 401, not authorized message

All of my other POST methods are working fine, this is my call from android using retrofit

```
private void logout() {

        tokenManager = TokenManager.getInstance(getSharedPreferences("prefs",MODE_PRIVATE));
        Log.i("tokenLogout",tokenManager.getToken().getAccessToken());
        call = service.logout(tokenManager.getToken());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<AccessToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AccessToken> call, Response<AccessToken> response) {

                Log.i(TAG, "logout response: " + response.code());
                //startActivity(new Intent(mapActivity.this,loginActivity.class));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AccessToken> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, "logout failed");
            }
        });
    }
```

and this is my ApiService interface

```
@POST("logout")
        @FormUrlEncoded
        Call<AccessToken> logout(@Field("access_token") AccessToken accessToken);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
Call<AccessToken> logout(@Header("Authorization") String token,@Field("access_token") AccessToken accessToken);
```

and in you code use

```
call = service.logout("Bearer : XXXXX",tokenManager.getToken());
```

I recommend you use HttpLoggingInterceptor in order to see all log about your request . url: https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor